# ranking items in multiple lists based on position

Tags: ruby, list, sorting

I've got multiple lists with elements that may appear in one or more than one of the lists. I need to sort the lists into one list showing the overall ranking.
Example:

```
  List 1 |  List 2  |   List 3
1. Book  | 1. Car   | 1. Glass
2. Car   | 2. Bike  | 2. Car
3. Bike  | 3. Apple | 3. Apple
```

So, it's obvious that `Car` is going to be ranked first. But what should I be looking for to rank these items in a list?

I have seen some `C` code that I think shows how it's done, but I don't understand that. I could figure it out using `Ruby`, or maybe even `Python` but the algorithm is something I am struggling to find. Even an `Excel` formula would work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to specify a ranking measure. For example, you could rank items by the sum the ranks of in each list. "Car", then, would have an overall rank of 2+1+2=5. Is that a good ranking criteria? How should I know? Moreover, there's a problem with that measure if some elements do not appear in all lists. The point is that you must decide what criteria you want to use to determine an overall ranking. That is not something that readers can recommend. Moreover, there's nothing we can do to help you without such a measure.

Comment: Hi Cary. I supposed the criteria is the difficult bit. Giving the car 2+1+2=5 won't really work I think. Neither will giving the highest in the list a lower score and giving the the 'lowest score' on the list the highest ranking, as it doesn't consider items that don't appear. The lists are different lengths also. It's maybe too complex. Although in theory it's simple: give the items that appear higher on the lists more often the higher rankings, compared to the others.

Comment: Let's say items in 1st place (1.) get 100 points. Items in 2nd place get 90, 3rd place get 80, and so on. Then I add the 'points' together and the item with the highest number of points goes to 1st place on a final list. Is there a good method in Ruby for doing this? (the lists would be plain text files or an output from a ruby program. Rank would be simply the position in the list)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Iterate through the list of the words in excel.
 Store the words as the dictionary key.

If the dictionary key is found then add the ranking number to the value. If the dictionary key is not found then create a key for the same  and add the ranking number..

```
Eg.,.  

if word in dict.keys():
   dict[word] += rank_number
else:
   dict[word] = rank_number
```

Step 2 : Sort the dictionary based on value( from low value to high value).

Comment: Note the presence of a "Ruby" tag and the absence of an "Excel" tag.

Comment: Should I always put the Excel tag even though I'd prefer to work this out in Ruby? I'm new to StackOverflow so just checking. It would be much easier to keep the solution out of excel, but of course if that's the only way I can do it then that's good enough. I added excel in there as a last resort.

Comment: The person asking the question decides what tags are appropriate and species them as part of the question. The fact that the question has a Ruby tag indicates the the asker wants answers that use Ruby to solve the problem.